# Is there any program that gives you air temperature (and precipitation) information if you feed them the date and location (latitude,longitude)?

Tags: meteorology, software

I know I can google each data point (latitude, longitude, date) one by one and find if the government of that country has archived past weather information. But this will take infinite amount of time for large datasets in a wide range of date and location worldwide. Is there any way to get around this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to look into global earth system models (commonly used by climate scientists) - although this will give you fairly coarse-resolution modelled information rather than measurements. A reanalysis product might be better, if there's a suitable global one. Hopefully somebody who actually knows will be along ;-)

Comment: @ychung OPeNDAP and THREDDS is one protocol. Check it out

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 may or may not be helpful